# Looking for a JavaScript implementation of node's "util.inherits"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am implementing a JavaScript library that can also run on node, and I'd like to use node's API as much as possible. My objects emit events, so I found this nice library called [eventemitter2](https://github.com/hij1nx/EventEmitter2), and which reimplements EventEmitter for JavaScript. Now I'd like to find the same for [util.inherits](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor). Has anybody heard about such a project ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried using the Node.js implementation? (It uses `Object.create`, so it [may or may not work on the browsers you care about](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/)). Here's the implementation, from https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/util.js:

```
inherits = function(ctor, superCtor) {
  ctor.super_ = superCtor;
  ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
    constructor: {
      value: ctor,
      enumerable: false,
      writable: true,
      configurable: true
    }
  });
};
```

Another method is used by CoffeeScript, which compiles

```
class Super
class Sub extends Super
```

to

```
var Sub, Super,
  __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
  __extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; };

Super = (function() {

  function Super() {}

  return Super;

})();

Sub = (function(_super) {

  __extends(Sub, _super);

  function Sub() {
    return Sub.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  return Sub;

})(Super);
```

Comment: That's a very good idea ... I didn't think about that ! And in fact all the browsers I care about support it ... great ! About coffee script ... I think it is a very bad idea to use it to implement a library.

Comment: The point wasn't to use CoffeeScript, but to examine how it handles prototype inheritance via the `__extends` method it creates, which is similar to `util.inherits`.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I read too quickly. Yeah, at the moment that's a similar method I am using. But the node implementation is better since I can just use the "native" method when the lib is running on node.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to use any external library. Just use javascrit as is.

B inherits from A

```
B.prototype = Object.create (A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;
```

And inside the constructor of B:

```
A.call (this, params...);
```

If you know that javascript has a property named constructor, then avoid it, no need to hide or not enumerate it, avoid avoid avoid. No need to have a super property, simply use A.call. This is javascript, don't try to use it like any other language because you will miserably fail.

Comment: shouldn't it be this? 
`B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype); 
B.prototype.constructor = B;`

Comment: This is exactly what I've been doing, and I'm glad I've found some reinforcement for my own logic and practice.  I feel some developers (even those of popular products) abuse Javascript.  So this answer gets my vote - 2 lines, 1 function call.  Consider Node.js' util.inherits: first you have to "require" util, 1 function call (doing who knows what), then you call member function util.inherits (2 lines, 2 function calls), and within that function it creates an additional object with 4 properties as the descriptor.  I don't even want to discuss the abortion that is CoffeeScript's solution.